# wget: save with .jpg extension

Tags: html, linux, download, jpeg, wget

I made this script to download .jpg files from a database:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i +=1))
do
wget http://archives.cg66.fr/mdr/index.php/docnumserv/getSubImage/0/0/0/-archives-009NUM_Etat_civil-Images---LLUPIA-2E1700_1702-FRAD066_2E1700_1702_000$i.jpg/0/100/0/100/100/100/100/100/2300/1500/0/100
done
```

because of the "/0/100/0/100/100..." after the .jpg extension, the result is:

9 files named:
100 , 100.1, 100.2, 100.3 ... 100.9

and I would find a way to have 9 .jpg files named 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg, 0003.jpg ... 0009.jpg

Could you give me some help or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coud try this way:

```
~$ URL1="http://archives.cg66.fr/mdr/index.php/docnumserv/getSubImage/0/0/0/-archives-009NUM_Etat_civil-Images---LLUPIA-2E1700_1702-FRAD066_2E1700_1702"
~$ URL2="0/100/0/100/100/100/100/100/2300/1500/0/100"
~$ for I in $(seq -w 0001 0009)
   do
      wget -O "${I}.jpg" "${URL1}_${I}.jpg/${URL2}"
   done
```

To populate the `i` variable with three leading zeros I use `seq -w 0001 0009`. To download images with the right filename I use `wget -O "${i}.jpg" ${URL}`. This work also with more than 9 images, eg. to produce a sequence of numbers from 1 to 999 with the leading zeros (`0001 ... 0099 ... 0999`) the command becomes `seq -w 0001 0999`.

See `man seq` and `man wget` for the documentation (online [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Option-Syntax)).

Of course the URL can't contain leading zeros between the variable `${i}` and the underscore, otherwise the `wget` command will return an error page.

For this reason I changed the URL from this: `..._1702_000$i.jpg/0/100/...` to this: `..._1702_${i}.jpg/0/100/...`.

The downloaded files:

```
~$ ls -l 
total 20404
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2408227 Oct  9 22:38 0001.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2422199 Oct  9 22:38 0002.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2330667 Oct  9 22:38 0003.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2162542 Oct  9 22:38 0004.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2579155 Oct  9 22:38 0005.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2175118 Oct  9 22:38 0006.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2174325 Oct  9 22:38 0007.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2421311 Oct  9 22:38 0008.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ale ale 2202587 Oct  9 22:38 0009.jpg
```

---

EDIT: Another alternative. First I create a file with list URL:

```
~$ URL1="http://archives.cg66.fr/mdr/index.php/docnumserv/getSubImage/0/0/0/-archives-009NUM_Etat_civil-Images---LLUPIA-2E1700_1702-FRAD066_2E1700_1702"
~$ URL2="0/100/0/100/100/100/100/100/2300/1500/0/100"
~$ for I in $(seq -w 0001 0009)
   do
      echo "${URL1}_{${I}}.jpg/${URL2}" >> url_list.txt
   done
```

The loop outputs URLs formatted this way: `..._1702_{${I}}.jpg/0/100...` in order to save files with the format: `'#1.jpg'`.

```
~$ xargs -P 10 -n 1 curl -o '#1.jpg' < url_list.txt
```

However, this solution may overload the webserver. In case of troubles, I think might be helpful to use the `wget` solution adding the option `--limit-rate=amount` to limit download speed to `amount` bytes per seconds. Add `k` for kilobytes, `M` for megabytes.

References:

- Command parallelization and fetching one argument from file (`xargs -n 1 -P {number_files}`): https://serverfault.com/a/722874
- Saving file with custom name (`curl -o '#1.jpg'`): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91574